# Prevent validate on ng-disabled field in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJs when I am submitting a form ng-disabled field also being validated. How to prevent this by being validated?

```
<select ng-disabled="true" class="select-apm" ng-model="customizeForm.AppId" name="listOption" ng-options="sortOption.appid as sortOption.appname for sortOption in sortOptions" required>
<option value="">{{'global.no.items.selected'|translate}}</option>
```

```
<div class="modal-footer">          
        <button type="submit" class="pull-right" ng-click="customapp()" translate>global.save</button>
</div>
```

It should be validated only when the ng-disabled is false.

Comment: How you are validating? use angular.form ?

Comment: submit-valid="customapp()"@PraveenPrasannan

Comment: Add your validation code, it will help us to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

You could assign a value of ng-disabled in your controller example

in **view**

```
<select ng-disabled="value" class="select-apm" ng-model="customizeForm.AppId" name="listOption" ng-options="sortOption.appid as sortOption.appname for sortOption in sortOptions" required>
<option value="">{{'global.no.items.selected'|translate}}</option>
```

in **controller**

```
angular.controller('xxx',function($scope){
 //Based on your Problem Domain
 $scope.value = true or false 
});
```